# Getting/setting a state object (vanilla js)

Tags: javascript, state

I've tried looking for duplicates, but always get React answers (understandably).

Just wondering if this gets and sets the state object in a way that will prevent unintended 'smells' because of references to/mutating the original state object.

Apologies if this seems easy, but I'm just unsure. Very interested in better/best practice if it's not classified as too broad.

```
let state = {
  name: 'Nick',
  sex: 'male',
  hobbies: []
}

const updateHobbies = async() => {
  const hobbies = // some fetch call
   
  setState('hobbies', hobbies);
}

const setState = (key, value) => {
  state = { ...state, 'key': value }
}
const getState = () => {
  return { ...state }
}
```

Comment: Surely in this case your wanting to mutate, it's state after all.

Comment: ` state = { ...state, 'key': value }` you need `[key]` instead of `'key'`

Comment: Also `return { ...state }` You still have a mutation issue here, spread syntax is only a shallow copy, IOW: `hobbies` will still be a mutable object.

Comment: What does IOW mean here?

Comment: IOW = In other words..

Comment: how would you delete a property?

Comment: @Keith in addition, it's the same problem with a call like `setState("name", "Fred)` - the `hobbies` array is still mutable and shared between both the old and new state objects.

Comment: @VLAZ  Yeah, that's what I was meaning.  Ironically it's only if setting `setState('hobbies', [...])` it's going to be OK. :)

Comment: Some state machines expect a mutated existing object, others expect a new one, so it depends.

Comment: @Keith I was just assuming I wanted to avoid some (admittedly fictional) scenario where the calling function might still be using the object. You may well be correct!

Comment: @Keith and thanks for the shallow copy point. So am I trying to achieve something I probably shouldn't try without an actual state management library?

Comment: @NickW  Yeah, I didn't explain that well.  It was mainly your `setState` function trying to prevent mutation, were mutation is an issue you have your `getState` guarding against it.

Comment: @Keith that makes sense - no need to guard against it when setting because you never access the original state object. But if shallow copies are still a problem should I abandon this approach or just look to change how I make the copy?

Comment: @NickW  There is nothing wrong in rolling your own, a deep copy is pretty trivial to implement.  It all depends what your objectives are..

Comment: IMO, it's better to just use an existing implementation that provides you immutable records. Like Immutable.JS but also other libraries. Cloning is easy to do but can also be expensive with a lot of calls. If many objects are created and discarded, you'd get a lot more GC runs. Immutable data structures tend to avoid that via structural sharing, rather than re-creating the entire structure and sacrificing the old one to the garbage collector. Also, no real need to re-create the wheel when easy alternatives are around. Although it might be an interesting researach.

Comment: @Keith at present I'm just aiming to make a solid MVC boilerplate for use in future vanilla js apps that doesn't involve weird state surprises down the line. Pretty vague, I know, but was interested in how to do it

Comment: @VLAZ Interesting, thanks. I'll definitely take a look at ImmutableJS and good to know about the cost of cloning. Does this problem of shallow copies evaporate by having setters for individual state properties, or those that are objects themselves, rather than the entire state object?

Comment: @NickW the problem with the shallow copies is only there because any values which are objects will be shared. Consider `oldHobbies = state.hobbies; state = { ...state }; oldHobbies.push("Tennis"); console.log(state.hobbies)` - you'd find that the new state has been  "modified". Of course, that's not actually true - old and new state have the same `hobbies` array. So, adding individual setters doesn't address that. Consider another example - the state has a *second* array value, let's say `pets`. https://jsbin.com/vilohacibi/edit?js,console

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah, I was thinking more along the lines of a `getter` that grabbed the `hobbies` array and spread that. Something like: `getHobbies() { const newHobbies = state.hobbies; return [...newHobbies] }`? But since then I've realised that that only really works if the array doesn't contain objects itself, so it's the same problem and not much use :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like pointed out, using tried and tested libs is certainly a good idea.  But sometimes rolling your own isn't a bad idea, especially for learning purposes etc.

Below I have created a little snippet with a basic deep copy.

You will notice the shallow copy `{...}` version will change `a`, but the `deepCopy` doesn't.

Be nice if ES spec implements a deep copy, sometimes people just do -> `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` and that's not great, as it will loose lots of data types, like Date etc.  Of course cloning an object is not simple, as special care for Object types need taking care, eg. My snippet has to specifically handle Dates, other Object might also need special care. But maybe this could be done using the same technique Iterration has been done with `Symbol.iterator`..

```js
const CloneSymbol = Symbol('clone');

Date.prototype[CloneSymbol] = 
  d => new Date(d.getTime());
  
//custom Person object with clone.  
class Person {
  constructor (first, last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
  }
  get full() { return `${this.first} ${this.last}` }
}
Person.prototype[CloneSymbol] = s => {
  return new Person(s.first, s.last);
}
  
  

const deepCopy = obj => {
  const m = Object.entries(obj).map(
    ([k, v]) => {
       if (v === null) return [k, v];
       if (typeof v === 'object') {           
         const fn = v.constructor
           .prototype[CloneSymbol];
         return [k, fn ? fn(v) : deepCopy(v)]
       } else return [k, v];
    }
  );
  return Array.isArray(obj) 
    ? m.reduce((a, [i, v]) => {
      a[i] = v;
      return a;
    }, [])
    : Object.fromEntries(m);
}


const a = {
  nullVal: null,
  seven: 7,
  person: new Person('bill', 'clinton'),
  date: new Date(),
  one: 'one',
  arr: ['hello', 'there', [1,2,3]]
}

//deep copy, b has no mutation
//a is not effect..
const b = deepCopy(a);
b.arr[0] = 'bye';
b.date.setDate(1);
b.arr[2].push(4);
console.log(b.person.full);


//shalow copy, look at a & c
const c = {...a}; 
c.arr[1] = 'oops';

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
console.log(a.person === b.person);
```

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. I get the issue of shallow copies, but that's a great demo of it. Could this also be solved by coding for a specific state object? So my `getter` could manually copy a known array and add it to the otherwise shallow copy? Or I could just never export the state object, and simply have getters for individual properties (that happen to mutable objects?)

Comment: @NickW  I've updated the `deepCopy` to use `Symbol`, so you can implement custom clone for special Classes etc.  If that's what you mean..  Here I've just implemented Date, but say you had a Class called Person etc, you could implement clone for it.

Comment: That's awesome - I surprisingly think I understand all of that, even if it did take me a while! Useful, thanks. But no, what I was trying to describe was a way of avoiding a deep copy entirely, but thinking about it that would be a nightmare with multiple nested objects. Out of interest, if you had the choice, would you use this deep copy, implement something like this (redux clone) https://www.antoniovdlc.me/one-way-state-management-in-vanilla-javascript/, or implement a state library? (any recommendations?)

Comment: thanks again btw, enjoyed looking at that answer (if only because it makes me think I'm better than I thought XD)

Comment: About state lib's,  I've never been a fan of Redux type state managers, I ended making my own using proxy's.  But have you ever seen solidJs, it's similar to React but with some really nice state handling built in.  https://www.solidjs.com/

Comment: That does look decent, will definitely check that out for another project, but for this one (a portfolio piece) I was keen to show that I could build something relatively complex without a framework. Think I'll probably implement the above deepcopy function in my `getter` and leave the `setter`, as you suggested. Thanks for all the help, really appreciate it

Comment: Actually, just quickly (so I don't have to come back here at a later date!) -> the code where you add a Symbol to the object's prototype, is for adding custom code to correctly copy a custom object, but have you got any other examples of how it would work outside of Date? I just can't get my head round what else I'd use it for. Even a custom class could be copied using the `deepCopy` method, no?

Comment: @NickW  No problem, I'll quickly knock up the classic Person class..

Comment: @NickW Ok, done.  Notice how `b.person.full` still works on `b`,  and `a.person` is a different object to `b.person`..